# MySQL several max in query

Tags: mysql

I have come across a problem I have not been able to solve.
I have the following table:

```
TABLE Sales (
  ClientCode varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  DocumentDate date NOT NULL,
  ItemCode varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  ItemName varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  Quantity decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  Price decimal(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  InvoiceType varchar(9) NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

All sales are recorded in this table.

There are 3 types of invoices (InvoiceType). I need a query that gives a result like

```
ClientCode, ItemCode, ItemName, LastDateofSaleforInvoiceA, LastSalePriceforInvoiceA, LastDateofSaleforInvoiceB, LastSalePriceforInvoiceB, LastDateofSaleforInvoiceC, LastSalePriceforInvoiceC
```

I don't know if I am explaining this clearly but I need one row that has the customerCode, ItemCode, ItemName and the last date and last Price for each of the invoice types we have.

Source data is like this:

```
+------------+--------------+----------+----------+----------+-------+-------------+

| ClientCode | DocumentDate | ItemCode | ItemName | Quantity | Price | InvoiceType |

+------------+--------------+----------+----------+----------+-------+-------------+

|      00001 | 2018-10-01   |    00001 | WidgetA  |      500 | 5.00  | Internal    |

|      00002 | 2018-09-27   |    00005 | WidgetB  |      100 | 1.50  | External    |

|      00001 | 2017-09-23   |    00001 | WidgetA  |      150 | 2.25  | External    |

|      00002 | 2016-03-03   |    00005 | WidgetB  |      360 | 5.99  | Internal    |

|      00001 | 2013-03-03   |    00001 | WidgetA  |      600 | 0.99  | Export      |    
+------------+--------------+----------+----------+----------+-------+-------------+
```

What I need is something like this:

```
+------------+----------+------------------+---------------+------------------+---------------+----------------+-------------+
| ClientCode | ItemCode | LastDateInternal | PriceInternal | LastDateExternal | PriceExternal | LastDateExport | PriceExport |
+------------+----------+------------------+---------------+------------------+---------------+----------------+-------------+
|      00001 |    00001 | 2018-10-01       | 5.00          | 2017-09-23       | 2.25          | 2013-03-03     | 0.99        |
|      00002 |    00005 | 2016-03-03       | 5.99          | 2018-09-27       | 1.50          |                |             |
+------------+----------+------------------+---------------+------------------+---------------+----------------+-------------+
```

All help is appreciated.

Comment: What version of MySQL ?

Comment: have a select query you tried that no good ?

Comment: What are allowed values for `InvoiceType` ? You need to provide some sample data, and expected output

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I am using mySQL 5.7 I have tried many select statements but none give me what I want of I get "mysql server went away" and I have to retry.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subquery for find the max(DocumentDate) grouped  by Client and InvoceType
then you could join this result with sales 3 times  each time for  different invoceType

```
select a.ClientCode
    , a.ItemCode
    , a.ItemName
    , a.DocumentDate as LastDateofSaleforInvoiceA
    , a.Price as LastSalePriceforInvoiceA
    , b.DocumentDate as LastDateofSaleforInvoiceB
    , b.Price as  LastSalePriceforInvoiceB
    , b.DocumentDate as LastDateofSaleforInvoiceC
    , b.PriceC as LastSalePriceforInvoiceC 
from (
    select max(DocumentDate) max_date, InvoiceType, ClientCode
    from Sales 
    group by InvoiceType, cliendtCode
) t 
inner join sales a on t.ClientCode = a.ClientCode
    AND t.max_date = a.DocumentDate
        AND t.InvoiceType = a.InvoceType
inner join sales b on t.ClientCode = a.ClientCode
    AND t.max_date = b.DocumentDate
        AND t.InvoiceType = b.InvoceType
inner join sales c on t.ClientCode = a.ClientCode
    AND t.max_date = c.DocumentDate
        AND t.InvoiceType = c.InvoceType
```

Comment: @Strawberry  .  thanks  for suggestion added  the clientcode in group by

Answer (score 0):

I assume that DocumentDate is datetime and practically unique (one sale at a time) 
I also assume that the relationship between ItemCode and ItemName is 1to1

A nested query is needed to get the last date, and a join to get the corresponding price

```
    SELECT
    last.ClientCode, last.ItemCode, last.ItemName, last.InvoiceType, MAX(If(InvoiceType = 'A', s.LastDate, 0)) as LastDateofSaleforInvoiceA, s.Price AS  LastSalePriceforInvoiceA
    # The same for B and C
    (
    SELECT
    ClientCode, ItemCode, ItemName, InvoiceType, Price, MAX(DocumentDate) as LastDate
    FROM
     sales
    GROUP BY
    ClientCode, ItemCode, InvoiceType
    ) last
    INNER JOIN sales s ON last.ClientCode = s.ClientCode AND last.ItemCode = s.ItemCode AND last.InvoiceType = s.InvoiceType AND last.LastDate = s.DocumentDate

GROUP BY
last.ClientCode, last.ItemCode, last.InvoiceType
```